# How to configure an SMS gateway in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sms, gateway

I recently purchase a sms gateway for my wordpress website. However, they do not give any plugin. They give me php code, like bellow. I want to use this for User registration verification / Order Verification / Forget Password / How to do this? I am using Basic OceanWP theme with elementor-free version.

```
<?php
    // Account details
    $username = 'Your Username';
    $apiKey = 'Your API Key';
    $apiRequest = 'Text';
    // Message details
    $numbers = '9890098900,9890098901'; // Multiple numbers separated by comma
    $sender = 'HLPDSK';
    $message = 'This is your message';
    $templateid = "DLT Template ID";
    // Route details
    $apiRoute = 'TRANS';
    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = 'username='.$username.'&apikey='.$apiKey.'&apirequest='.$apiRequest.'&route='.$apiRoute.'&mobile='.$numbers.'&sender='.$sender."&TemplateID=".$templateid."&message=".$message;
    // Send the GET request with cURL
    $url = 'http://www.hostname.com/sms-panel/api/http/index.php?'.$data;
    $url = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $url);
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    // Process your response here
    echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: We can't tell you how to integrate some code with three different parts of your site about which we know nothing.

Comment: This is not a code writing service, So please do some research and share your particular issues.